# how to make JTable display all records form database

Tags: java, swing

My problem is when i run the program the data displayed at the JTable but not all records are displayed although i have a scroll Pane and aJtable inside it,when i run it provides a scroll but for the firs few records ,the jtable have a textfield to provide searching in table using rowSorter ,although jtable doesn't show all records when i search for a record that is not viewed i gets it.this is an image describing the problem.please how can i fix that.
this is the link i have no permission to attache an image here
http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/561971/Untitled-jpg.html 
this is piece of code where i initialize these component

```
    table2 = new JTable(tableModel);


    table2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    table2.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));


    scrollPane_1.setColumnHeaderView(table2.getTableHeader());
    table2.setBackground(new Color(210, 180, 140));
    table2.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(105, 105, 105)));
    table2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    sorter2 = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table2.getModel());
    table2.setRowSorter(sorter2);
    JViewport vp2 = new JViewport();
    vp2.setBackground(new Color(210, 105, 30));
    vp2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    scrollPane_1.setViewportView(vp2);
    vp2.add(table2);
```

this is the method that fill the table

```
    table2Data = new Vector<>();
    Iterator<SellBean> buyIt = boughtedList.iterator();
    while (buyIt.hasNext()) {
        SellBean buyBean = buyIt.next();
        Vector rec = new Vector<>();

        rec.add(buyBean.getPRODUCT_ID());

        rec.add(buyBean.getPRODUCT_NAME());
        // System.out.println(buyBean.getPRODUCT_NAME());
        rec.add(buyBean.getQUANTITY());
        rec.add(buyBean.getBUY_PRICE());
        rec.add(buyBean.getSELL_PRICE());
        rec.add(buyBean.getPROFIT());
        rec.add(buyBean.getBUY_DATE());
        rec.add(buyBean.getRETURNED());
        table2Data.add(rec);
    }
    tm2.setDataVector(table2Data, table2ColNames);
    for (int i = 0; i < table2.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        table2.getColumnModel().getColumn(i)
                .setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < table2.getRowCount(); i++) {

        table2.setRowHeight(i, 28);
    }
    table2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(25);
}
```

i hope it is clear now

Comment: This question as written is a `"guess why the code I'm not showing you is not working"` type question. Please fix this by creating and posting your [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to review, test, and possibly fix. With just a little more work on your part, you'll likely get some decent answers soon.

Comment: I'm still not sure where your bug is. Again, consider creating and posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this methods gets all records from DB table but Jtable does not show all the retrieved records it show only the first few record although it provides scroll.can you see the image?

Comment: No, I can't see the image, but what is **much**  more important, we need to see the code causing the problem, and we need to be able to understand this code. I'm sorry to harp on this over and over, but if you need our help, need it bad, and need it quickly, your best bet is to create and post your [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's your problem and your time, that's at issue here, so it's entirely up to you what you want to do, but if I were in your shoes, this is what I'd do.

Comment: which database are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have problems with the scrollpane (like: no scrollbars visible).
Are your sure you are using it correct?
this looks strange to me:
You create a ViewPort and put this as View?!

```
JViewport vp2 = new JViewport();
scrollPane_1.setViewportView(vp2);
vp2.add(table2);
```

why not just set the Table as ViewportView (as the name implies?)
just:

```
scrollPane_1.setViewportView(table2);
```

**Edit**: Info about the ViewPort:
The "viewport" or "porthole" through which you see the underlying information. When you scroll, what moves is the viewport. It is like peering through a camera's viewfinder. Moving the viewfinder upwards brings new things into view at the top of the picture and loses things that were at the bottom.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html

Comment: +1 in addition if you pass in the table as argument when you instantiate the scroll pane, this will be automatically set as its view port.

Comment: It has worked as i want, thank you ,but i have a question you said "You create a ViewPort and put this as View?! why not just set the Table as ViewportView (as the name implies?)  i put the table in viewPort and set the viewport to scrollpane , if this is wrong so what is  the importance of the JViewPort